# Is there much overhead in having many MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an application that now has three Areas and each have around eight different route definitions.  In the future I may need to add more.

From a performance point of view is there much overhead to having this number of definitions?

Is there any performance benefit to be gained by having the most common route show up first?

Comment: Eight of anything sounds quite small to me, in the context of computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal to have more routes, but you need to know that **regexp** constraint is working very slow. 
 You cannot place most common route first because then all other routes will never work.